# Java newInstance("Sample") returns classNotFoundException when it shouldn't

Tags: java

I was studying Dependency injection in Spring for sometimes & got to step back on java basics as I was exhausted getting errors. So, quick brief of below chunk of code of mine would be to maintain independent between classes. with regards to the code written below, When I try executing the code it always throws for ClassNotFoundException & terminates the execution. Please help me on this.

```
//Main class

class Main{

 public static void main(String []args){

 try{

  Car c = carFactory.getCar("Axio");
  c.print();

  }catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
}

//Car Interface

public interface Car{
 public void print();   
}

//Car Interface implementation class

class Axio implements Car{

 public void print(){
  System.out.println("Axio car is called...");
 }

}

//Car Factory class

class carFactory{

 public static Car getCar(String carName)throws Exception{

  return (Car)Class.forName(carName).newInstance(); 

 }

}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Also do some research on the exception name - most likely you simply forget about package names - or you messed up your classpath settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing the fully qualified name of the class in `Class.forName()` and it should work.

Comment: Could you please re-write the code for me?.

Comment: you're correct, the class should be followed by any packages assigned onto

Comment: The code seems fine, you just need to use the package name as well. What is the package name for all your classes?

Comment: Something like `Car c = carFactory.getCar("com.foo.mypack.somename." + "Axio");`

Comment: Yes, exactly the code now being executing well without any failure. Thanks, all.

Comment: @FarhanDulip glad I could help. :)

Comment: But what if the classes are located in the default package?

Comment: The answer is simple: no package name is required. Do you use any IDE?

Comment: Yes, I'm using NetBeans

Comment: I use eclipse and when I right-click on a class Declaration, it gives me the option to Copy Qualified Name. Do you receive similar option there? That name is btw, what you need to call in reflection.

Comment: Nope, I do not find any option as such on my end. By the way, I can declare the fully qualified path manually.& Hope, I will never repeat such mistake again. Thanks!!

Comment: Saw it. there isn't an option and you'll have to write that manually. Sad.